# Best practices for defining your own exception classes?

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, error-handling

I have some special exception cases that I want to throw and catch, so I want to define my own exception classes.

What are the best practices for that? Should I inherit from `std::exception` or `std::runtime_error`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it's good practice to [inherit](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#what-to-throw) from `std::runtime_error` or the [other standard exception classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) like `std::logic_error`, `std::invalid_argument` and so on, depending on which kind of exception it is.

If all the exceptions inherit some way from `std::exception` it's easy to catch all common errors by a `catch(const std::exception &e) {...}`. If you have several independent hierarchies this gets more complicated. Deriving from the specialized exception classes makes these exceptions carry more information, but how useful this really is depends on how you do your exception handling.

Comment: The suggestion to catch by const reference was taken up on the same day.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a C++ developer, but one thing we did in our C# code was create a base class exception for our framework, and then log the exception thrown in the constructor:

```
  public FrameworkException(string message, Exception innerException)
      : base(message, innerException)
  {
      log.Error(message, innerException);
  }

  ...
```

Any derived exception just has to invoke it's base constructor and we get consistent exception logging throughout. Not a big deal, but useful.

Comment: You have to be careful with fancy exceptions though, especially when construction of the exception itself may throw exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good when exception is placed in some scope. For instance class Manipulation can declare inside exception classes Error.

and catch them like

```
catch ( const Manipulation::InputError& error )
catch ( const Manipulation::CalculationError& error )
```

In such cases they can be just empty classes without any additional error information unless you design allows those exceptions fly much upper where you catch all standard exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it doesn't matter if you inherit from std::exception or not.  For me the most important thing about defining exceptions are:

1. Having the exception class names be useful and clear.
2. Clearly documenting (writing comments) when exception will get thrown by a function or class method.  This is the single biggest failure point in exception handling in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a big difference, since `std::runtime_error` also inherits from `std::exception`. You could argue that runtime error conveys more information about the exception, but in practice, people often just derive from the base exception class.

Comment: If you handle (i.e. catch) exceptions by subtype, but still want to pass `std::string` messages along with them, isn't it much easier to build your exceptions on `std::runtime_error`? Wouldn't this enable for the rule of zero when defining subclasses?