# runtime_error expecting a ";"?

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax

I am trying to use inheritance to create a class derived from `runtime_error`, but I keep getting an error even though this is the exact code used in exercises and as an example from the book. Here is the code:

```
class DivideZeroEx : public runtime_error
{
    public:
        DivideZeroEx()
            runtime_error( " attempt to divide by zero" )
};
```

Now I get an error stating that it expects a ; before the runtime_error("attempt to divide by zero") line.

Comment: In C/C++, you must end statements with a semicolon. Are you absolutely sure you haven't missed them off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax for calling your base class constructor should be:

```
DivideZeroEx() : runtime_error( " attempt to divide by zero" ) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it working like it should. So what other types of reasons can I use these types of runtime_error catches?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, but I'd say that you could create a derived class for every distinct exception that you need, potentially grouping them by category (e.g. using another layer of inheritance) if necessary. Take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/stdexcept/runtime_error/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688447/best-practices-for-defining-your-own-exception-classes) for some more information.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to call the Base class constructor in Member Initializer List, the syntax is:

```
DivideZeroEx():runtime_error( " attempt to divide by zero" )
{
}
```

Comment: @Sjoerd Utter nonsense. Why is the same answer by Vlad heavily upvoted, and this one downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

```
class DivideZeroEx : public runtime_error
{ 
public: 
   DivideZeroEx() : runtime_error( " attempt to divide by zero" ) 
   {
   }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In this instance it doesn't save much, but if you were to use `runtime_error` by name throughout your class, this is much easier to swap out the base in the future.

```
class DivideZeroEx : public runtime_error
{ 
typedef runtime_error base;

public: 
   DivideZeroEx() : base( " attempt to divide by zero" ) 
   {
   }
};
```